# Apache solr schema field not displaying in json result

Tags: php, apache, solr, lucene

I am using Apache solr-5.1.0 for searching pdf documents
I indexed all documents using bin/post method.

I added a custom field with curl like

```
 curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-field":{
     "name":"ZoneId",
     "type":"strings",
     "indexed" : true,
     "docValues":true,
     "stored":true }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/taxsutra/schema
```

Now when I invoke search query , this ZoneId is not displaying in json results.

Code to update index:

```
 curl http://localhost:8983/solr/taxsutra/update/json -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
[
 {"id" : "home/niyuj/projects/php/solr-5.1.0/../itat_src/Upload/KOLKATA/Kolkata/24-11-2014/307176844630250930713$5^1REFNOITA_No._1873.2012.pdf", "ZoneId" : "4"},
 {"id" : "/home/niyuj/projects/php/solr-5.1.0/../itat_src/Upload/KOLKATA/Kolkata/24-11-2014/-421302573392022465313$5^1REFNOITA-473-Kol-2014-Mathan-24_11.pdf", "ZoneId" : "5"}
]'
```

Comment: I can see zoneid field in schema file

Answer (score 2):

I cannot be sure with this information, but you don't see the field in the search query results because you don't have any document with values in this field. To check this, you can do this query: q=ZoneId:[* TO *]

Comment: thanks for reply, it given me 2 results which i had added with solr api(using curl) m, but I had updated one of the index value with zoneId but its not returning in query results

Comment: I am trying to implement in this way, I have to index pdf files in apache solr, and  I have database related to these files, once indexing is done , I need to  update the index with database field values, so I added database field to schema file (zoneId in this case) and trying to update the index using code given in description of my question ,but it creates new index instead, here unique id is nothing but the filepath , please let me know if i am going in wrong direction